# Android: startActivity() works for one activity but not another

Tags: java, android

Part of an app I'm working on has two buttons, and my problem is that when I call startActivity() it will work as expected for one activity but not another.

So this works:

```
startActivity(new Intent(StartScreenActivity.this, FiltersActivity.class));
```

But this does not:

```
startActivity(new Intent(StartScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
```

Both worked fine yesterday, but since updating Android Studio this morning nothing happens when I try to start MainActivity. Both are present in my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FiltersActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_filters"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

There are no errors thrown to the LogCat or anything like that, simply one works and nothing happens for the other. I would assume something is wrong with the MainActivity class, but it worked fine until a few hours ago and the only changes since then have been updating Studio, as I mentioned, and some small xml layout changes to the main activity layout file which I have tried undoing but that doesn't fix the problem.

---

Full manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".StartScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".FiltersActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_filters"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewVenue"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewMenuItemActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_new_menu_item"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

MainActivity.java:

```
package me.theglassboard.vee;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements VenueListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, LocationListener {

private VenueDao venueDao;
private ArrayList<Venue> venues;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location userLocation;

// Static strings to be used when putting and getting extras to/from intents
public static String MAX_PRICE = "maxPrice";
public static String MAX_DISTANCE = "maxDistance";
public static String ACCEPTS_CARD = "acceptsCard";
public static String WHEELCHAIR_ACCESS = "wheelchairAccess";
public static String SERVES_NON_VEGAN = "servesNonVegan";
public static float DEFAULT_MAX_DISTANCE = 5000;
public static int DEFAULT_MAX_PRICE = 999;

public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Request codes:
 *
 * Used in the MapFragment and ListFragment when adding a new
 * Venue or Menu Item. Those operations use startActivityForResult()
 * and the request code parameter of that method will be one of these
 * codes. They are therefor public static to ensure the fragments
 * have access, and final to ensure their values can't change at runtime.
 */
public static final int ADD_NEW_VENUE = 111;
public static final int ADD_NEW_MENU_ITEM = 222;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupLocation();
    //venueDao = new VenueDao(this);
    //venues = venueDao.getAllVenues();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Enable custom back button
    findViewById(R.id.toolbarLeftButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.toolbarLeftButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

private void searchVenues() {

    Log.d("INSIDE", "searchVenues()");

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int maxPrice = extras.getInt(FiltersActivity.MAX_PRICE, DEFAULT_MAX_PRICE);
    float maxDistance = extras.getFloat(FiltersActivity.MAX_DISTANCE, DEFAULT_MAX_DISTANCE);
    Boolean acceptsCard = extras.getBoolean(FiltersActivity.ACCEPTS_CARD, false);
    Boolean wheelchairAccess = extras.getBoolean(FiltersActivity.WHEELCHAIR_ACCESS, false);
    Boolean servesNonVegan = extras.getBoolean(FiltersActivity.SERVES_NON_VEGAN, false);

    GetVenuesTask getVenuesTask = new GetVenuesTask(
            (int)maxDistance,
            (float)userLocation.getLatitude(),
            (float)userLocation.getLongitude(),
            maxPrice,
            acceptsCard,
            wheelchairAccess,
            servesNonVegan,
            this);

    getVenuesTask.execute();

}

public void launchMainActivity(ArrayList<Venue> fetchedVenues) {

    Log.d("INSIDE", "launchMainActivity()");

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for both of the
    // primary sections of the activity.

    venues = fetchedVenues;

    //findViewById(R.id.loadingFrame).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(String id) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to both the map and list fragments
    // to perform whatever task they need to do.
    for(Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments())
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


/**
 * Fragment Adapter that returns either the VenueMap or VenueList fragments
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    VenueMapFragment mapFragment;
    VenueListFragment listFragment;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        if(position == 0/* && GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS*/) {
            mapFragment = VenueMapFragment.newInstance(venues);
            return mapFragment;
        }

        if(position == 1) {
            listFragment = VenueListFragment.newInstance(venues);
            return listFragment;
        }

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "MAP";
            case 1:
                return "LIST";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * The placeholder fragment initially provided by Studio.
 *
 * I am keeping it here for the time being as a default fragment
 * to be displayed if, for some reason, the map or list fragment
 * cannot be loaded.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    userLocation = location;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, this);
        searchVenues();
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    searchVenues();
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    //CODE
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    //CODE
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    //CODE
}

public void setupLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, this);
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(venues == null)
        finish();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, this);
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, this);
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
}
```

---

StartScreenActivity.java:

```
public class StartScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);

    VenueDao venueDao = new VenueDao(this);

    findViewById(R.id.startScreenGoButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("CLICKED", "Start Main Activity");
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(StartScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            mainActivity.putExtra(MainActivity.MAX_PRICE, MainActivity.DEFAULT_MAX_PRICE);
            mainActivity.putExtra(MainActivity.MAX_DISTANCE, MainActivity.DEFAULT_MAX_DISTANCE);
            mainActivity.putExtra(MainActivity.ACCEPTS_CARD, false);
            mainActivity.putExtra(MainActivity.WHEELCHAIR_ACCESS, false);
            mainActivity.putExtra(MainActivity.SERVES_NON_VEGAN, false);

            startActivity(mainActivity);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.startScreenFilterButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(StartScreenActivity.this, FiltersActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Post your MainActivity.java and full manifest

Comment: Try rebooting your phone/emulator.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I have the same one

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<activity>` in manifest with:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FiltersActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_filters"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="me.theglassboard.vee.FiltersActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="me.theglassboard.vee.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: No change when I do that, unfortunately.

Comment: why your MainActivity extends FragmentActivity??... change it with AppCompatActivity @KevinDoyle

Comment: It extends FragmentActivity because it contains fragments, this was the structure Android Studio generated so I went with it. Is there a particular reason for using AppCompatActivity instead here? Changing it to extending AppCompatActivity also didn't fix the problem, I'm afriad. Thank you for helping though!

Comment: Well to contain Fragment, you can use AppCompatActivity, and then use the Fragment in framelayout.

Answer (score -1):

Try the follow:

reference your button like this:

```
     mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
     mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
```

call your button with onClickListener

```
   mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent button1 = new Intent(StartScreenActivity.this, FiltersActivity.class);
                   startActivity(button1);
        }
   }    

   mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent button2= new Intent(StartScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(button);
        }
   }
```

if not working, send printout of the MainsActivity.class and StartScreenActivity